Stripe Create Invoice rest api giving error
**when i am testing this rest api it gives bellow error.
I am using spring boot and stripe.
 Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("customer", customerModel.getCustomerId());
        params.put("collection_method", form.getCollectionMethod());
        params.put("days_until_due", 30L);
        params.put("amount_due", form.getAmountDue());
  
> Invoice invoice = Invoice.create(params);
        return add(invoice,customerModel);
    }

Here is the error details :
**
It gives error for this parameter : amount_due but this parameter already listed their api documenation
for invoice object . **
https://docs.stripe.com/api/invoices/create
Error Log.
com.stripe.exception.InvalidRequestException:

Received unknown parameter: amount_due; code: parameter_unknown;
request-id: req_zqOjuJInpoNPUD

How can i solve this issue for unknown parameter : amount_due

amount_due is an attribute of the Invoice object, not a parameter.
It is not included as a parameter in the documentation you share.
You can't override the amount of an Invoice - the amount_due value will be determined by the invoice items, shipping and tax rates.
